Where do custom metrics I did not set come from
I explicitly track 4 metrics in my app and they all show up in the Azure Application Insights custom metrics. But this list of metrics also has 3 metrics I did not set:

HealthReportEntryDuration
HeartbeatState
TotalDuration

What are these and where did they come from? I do have Health Checks enabled. Also, the 1st & 3rd of these has numbers while the 2nd is flatlined at 0.


Those are the metrics which will be enabled if we configure health check from asp.net core.

Thanks @Peter Bons's for the Answer.
In addition, Please check the below Workaround.
I have created a sample Application Insights with default settings.
I haven't configured anything neither enabled Application Insights for my App.
Initially I don't see any metrics which you have mentioned.

I have just configured Application Insights from Connected Services in VS and deployed the app to Azure App Service.

Now Iam able to see the HeartbeatState metric.




You can also see the namespace details.
I can see this metrics for all my available applications which I have deployed

AFAIK,  HealthReportEntryDuration and TotalDuration are related to HealthCheck. Based on the installed packages related to the health check they might have enabled.

I have configured HealthCheck in my app.

My Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck("SampleCheck", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy(), tags: new[] { "sample" })
    .AddApplicationInsightsPublisher(); 

As per this MSDoc, totalDuration comes under Browser metrics.

To collect browser metrics, your application must be instrumented with the Application Insights JavaScript SDK.

so configured JavaScript SDK as well.

Now I am able to see the metrics which you have mentioned.


Also refer this MSDoc on Monitoring data reference -Azure Monitor for more details.

I know for a fact that the HeartbeatState is coming from the Application Insights integration, it is documented here:

Enable/Disable the Heartbeats feature, which periodically (15-min default) sends a custom metric named "HeartBeatState" with information about the runtime like .NET version and Azure environment, if applicable.

It has a value of 0 because it main purpose is to track wether te app is runnign and to report runtime information. (No idea why the choose 0 as a value).
The others I don't know but I think they are related to the Health Checks.
Thing is, the customMetrics table does not only contain metrics you emit from your application code. If the azure function runtime decides it want to publish some metrics as well they end up there as well. The same thing applies to libraries like Application Insights.
